# Vuejs router navigation guard working on first request, ignoring second time

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

(am new to Vue)
I have implemented a navigation guard on my router and it works when navigating from another route. The guard navigates the user to an access denied page. At this point the nav menu is still visible from the access denied page which means the user could try loading the page they were denied access to again. If the user does try doing this, the page they were previously denied access to loads and I would like to stop this happening. Seems to be bypassing the guard somehow?

Thanks

```
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) && !loggedIn) {
next({name: 'login'});

} else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.roles)) {

var userRoles = JSON.parse(loggedIn).roles;
to.meta.roles.forEach(function (role) {
  if (userRoles.includes(role))
    next();
});  
  next({ name:'accessdenied'});    
}
```

Router entry:-

```
{
path: '/pageA',
name: 'pageA',
component: pageA,
meta: { requiresAuth: true, roles: ['role1', 'role2'] },
beforeEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
  store.dispatch('fetchSomeData').then(() => {
    next()
  })
}
```

Nav entry:-

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'pageA'}">
            <h1 class="mb-0 h5 ml-4 z-app-header-title">Page A</h1>
 </router-link>
```

Comment: I'm not get what you mean, so you say when they already at the AccessDenied page, and they click at the nav menu, the page will load the AccessDenied page again and you dont want that ?

Comment: Sorry, no. So they try and load 'page a' but they don't have access and get sent to 'access denied'. There is a menu at the top where they can click a link to load 'page a' again. If they click it, it loads. It's like it's bypassing the guard somehow. I was thinking my router code must be incorrect and that it thinks it's successfully loaded 'page a' or something and isn't checking the second time. But I'm still getting to grips with Vue. Thanks

Comment: For this code its not really clear on all variable, can you post more code of the router js file, and also the Nav menu, especially parts related to user roles if any. There maybe some error outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly guard the route use something like this

```js
{
path: '/pageA',
name: 'pageA',
component: pageA,
meta: { requiresAuth: true, roles: ['role1', 'role2'] },
beforeEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
  if(!store.getters.loggedIn) next({name: 'login'});
  else if(!routeTo.meta.roles.includes(store.getters.userRole)) next({name: 'accessdenied
'});
  else next();
}
```

To guard all routes - use something like this

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>
{
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth) && !loggedIn) next({name: 'login'});

  else if (to.meta.roles)
  {
    const userRole = JSON.parse(loggedIn).role; // the role of the current user
    if(to.meta.roles.includes(userRole)) next();
    else next({ name:'accessdenied'});    
  }
  else next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the "guard all routes" option above and it works the first time - I see the access denied page. If you look at the "Nav entry" above, that is visible on the access denied page when it loads. If I click the nav entry, instead of the access denied page still being displayed "pageA" loads i.e. the access denied page dissapears and it loads PageA which was blocked the first time. Like the beforeEach was ignored the second time. thanks.

Comment: Please ignore, complete stupidity on my part, long week. Thanks!